# unable to change colors of a tag

Tags: javascript, css

i have this code

```
<a href="" id="mainLink">Click Me</a>
<a href="" id="mainLink2">Click Me 2</a>
```

And then the Js

```
  var mainLinker = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < mainLinker.length; i++) {
        this.style.color = 'red';
    }
```

But i get this error

```
Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
```

Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.

Comment: It should be `mainLinker[i].style...`. `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `this` scope relates to window or parent scope in this case, if you want to change particular element style in loop, use forEach or relate to that element as @Vohuman suggested.

Comment: Debug your program. Stop on the `this.style.color` line and examine `this` and see if it is what you think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not what you want.

Change the loop body to

```
mainLinker[i].style.color = 'red';
```

or equivalently use `forEach` (edited with @Vohuman's comment):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(el) {
    el.style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: You can't call the `.forEach` directly on the returned NodeList. You should at first convert it into a regular array. One option is `[].forEach.call(nodeList, function(el) { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You refer to `this`  in an object

Your function is not in an object

This will work

```
var mainLinker = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < mainLinker.length; i++) {
        mainLinker[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your basic problem is using `this`, as pointed out in other answers. But why are you doing this instead of using a CSS rule such as

```
a { color: red; }
```

If you want to make this conditional somehow, then add a class at a higher level, such as `body`, to control it:

```
body.make-links-red a { color: red }
```

Then, when you want to make links red, do

```
document.body.classList.add('make-links-red')
```